# How to check if a NavigationPath contains an NSManagedObject value?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

Suppose we have two very basic classes:

- a `NSManagedObject` class called `Item`
- and an `ObservableObject` class called `Navigation` to handle a `NavigationPath`

```
final class Navigation: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
}
```

I am looking to disable a `NavigationLink` when the `NavigationPath` contains a certain `Item` element, as shown in this example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var navigation = Navigation()
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigation.path) {
            List(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!.formatted())")
                }
                .disabled(navigation.path.contains(/* some Item */))
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(navigation)
    }
}
```

However to my surprise a `NavigationPath` has no `contains()` function. Any ideas please?

Comment: I am no expert on NavigationPath but I see it uses type erasure so it can handle different kinds of path objects so I don't understand how you could possibly treat it like a data source that can be searched, filtered etc.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to use `NavigationPath` to achieve what you want.
 You could try using the `items` instead.

Comment: Use array instead of a navigation path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
 @Published var path = NavigationPath()
```

To

```
 @Published var path: [Item] = []
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Not aware of this

Comment: Is there any way to check for an item if it's not just one type that the path contains?

Comment: @fer0n you can try “is” idk if it works but in theory should.